Edging to hide edge for profiled tiles
I have profiles tiles on which the edge is visible, and I would like to hide it with some kind of trim. The profile of the tile is not flat, so I am not sure what would be best to use in this situation. What are my options?


Are you planning to add a cabinet/wall there?  If not then need to add some trim(wood) or end/edge tiles(maybe tile maker has some).  Tiles cut like that are usually done meeting another surface/wall, not an empty space.

An edge made for tiles such as Schluter Jolly, should have been installed when the tiling was done.
Now your best bet is a small 1/4 round moulding or other wood moulding of your choice. Paint to your preference.

The problem is that the tiles are profiled.  If OP uses a Schluter trim tall enough to cover the cut edge, it will be too tall for the uncut edges, and if OP uses a trim short enough for the uncut edges, it will be too short to cover the cut edges.  Unless, I suppose, he grinds a tall profile trim to match the profiles.

@Huesmann, and that is the choice the OP must make.  I have seen many a profiled tile  edged with schluter. Once the grout is done it looks very good.
